# Calculating greatest common divisor and least common multiple modulo prime number

Tags: number-theory, modular-arithmetic

I'm trying to solve pretty complex problem with number theory and set of numbers.

To make the problem more clear we are going to define $GCD(a, b)$ as the greates number that divides both $a$ and $b$ and $LCM(a, b)$ as least common multiple of $a$ and $b$. For my problem I want to calculate both $GCD(x_1,\dots, x_n)$ and $LCM(x_1,\dots, x_n)$ for set of numbers $x_{i}\leq 300000$. But because we may have up to $10^5$ numbers I need to calculate this number modulo $p = 10^9 + 7$

My question is: If we are using Euclidean algorithm is it true that 
$$GCD(A, B) \text{ mod } p = GCD(A\text{ mod }p, B\text{ mod } p ) \text{ mod }p$$
$$\text{and}$$
$$LCM(A, B) \text{ mod } p = LCM(A\text{ mod }p, B\text{ mod } p ) \text{ mod }p$$

If we show that this is correct we can easily calculate those values in fast timing using the euclidean fast-gcd algorithm.

Comment: Which programming competition is this? "modulo 10^9 + 7" sounds very much like Project Euler.

Comment: It is not part of programing contests, it is just similar exercise for practice available on one site

Comment: Please credit the source of the problem.  A useful way is to link to the page on the site where you got this question from.

Answer (score 3):

$GCD$ and $LCM$ do not depend on an algorithm, they are mathematical functions on pair of integers.

The first statement is false. A counterexample: 
$$GCD(10, 17)\bmod{7} = 1 \bmod 7 = 1$$ but $$GCD(10 \bmod{7}, 17\bmod{7}) \bmod{7} = GCD(3, 3) \bmod 7 = 3 \bmod 7 = 3$$

The second is also false
$$ LCM(12, 18) \bmod 7 = 36 \bmod 7 = 1$$
but
$$ LCM(12 \bmod 7, 18 \bmod 7) \bmod 7 = LCM(5, 4) \bmod 7 = 20 \bmod 7 = 6$$

Comment: Thanks for the answer, is there a way to eficently calculate lcm of set of 100000 numbers modulo p?

Comment: What exactly do you want to compute? $GCD/LCM(x, y) \bmod p$ of $10^5$ numbers, and so $10^{10}$ pairs?

Comment: Noo i want to calculate two numbers, one number is the gcd of this set of numbers modulo p and the other one is lcm of those same numbers modulo p

Comment: In fact computing $LCM$ is reduced to computing $GCD$ since $LCM(x, y) = \frac{xy}{GCD(x,y))}$, so you need a fast $GCD$ algorithm. In such cases I consult to  "*The Art of Computer Programming" Volume 2, "Seminumerical Algorithms*" by D. Knuth.

Comment: I know the euclidean algorithm for calculating $GCD$ very fast, $GCD(x, y) = gcd(y, x mod y)$, but I dont know how to make it work with this modulo

Comment: Could you please show, using formulas, what you want to compute? $GCD(x \bmod p, y \bmod  p)$?

Comment: Let's define array A of size x, now I want to calculate $GCD(A_i) modulo p$ for each $1 \leq i \leq x$ where $p = 10^9 + 7$, I was thinking is it possible to calculate GCD for half of this array and then merge it for the other half?

Comment: I edited you question, did I understand you correctly?

Comment: Yes, it is good written now, sorry for writing it so bad.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/63408/discussion-between-fade2black-and-someone12321).

Comment: I coded for the whole array with prime factorization, i think that the complexity of my code is O(NlogN)